# Receiving NameError - how to fix?

Tags: python, regex, shell, bioinformatics, fasta

I am working on a project and am having issues with the following code that I have written in `nano`:

```
from Bio import SeqIO
import sys
import re 


    fasta_file = (sys.argv[1])
    for myfile in SeqIO.parse(fasta_file, "fasta"):
      if len(myfile) > 250:
       gene_id = myfile.id
       list = re.match('H149xcV\_\w+\_\w+\_\w+', gene_id)
       print (">"+list.group(1))
```

This is the error I receive when I execute my command on `command-line`:

```
File "mpo.py", line 7, in <module>
    gene_id = myfile.id
NameError: name 'myfile' is not defined
```

I have a fasta file with the format

```
>H149xcV_Fge342_r3_h2_d1 len=210 path=[0:0-206]
ACTATACATGAGGAGAACATAGAACAAAAATGGGACCATAGATATATAACAATAGAAGATATAGAGAACACAATAGACAACTTATTAGGAAAGAGGTGTGTCGTCATGGAGCTGATGTTCGAGGATACTTTGCATGGTCATTCTTGGATAATTTTGAGTGGGCTATGGGATACACCAAGAGGTTTGGCATTGTTTATGTTGATTATAAGAACGGGC

 >H149xcV_ytR1oP_r3_h2_d1 len=306 path=[0:0-207]
    ATTAGAGTCTGAGAGAGTCTTGATTTGTCGTCGTCGAGAAATATAGGAGATCTGATTAGAGGAGAGAGCGGCCTAGGCGATGCGCGATATAGCGCTATATAGGCCTAGAGGAGAGTCTCTCTCTTTTAGAAGAGATAATATATATATATATATGGCTCTCCGGCGGGGCCGCGCGAGAGCTCGATCGATCGATATTAGCTGTACGATGCTAGCTAGCTTATATTCGATCGATTATAGCTTAGATCTCTCTCTAAAGGTCGATATCGCTTATGCGCGCGTATATCG
```

I would like to reformat my file so that it only provides me with the unique gene id's and only output those genes id's with a length greater than 250 bp.

I would like my desired output to look like this:

```
>H149xcV_Fge342_r3_h2
>H149xcV_ytR1oP_r3_h2
>H149xcV_DPN78333_r3_h2
>H149xcV_AgV472_r3_h2
>H149xcV_DNP733_r3_h2
```

Comment: do you need double quotes around your regex? `re.match("H149xcV\_\w+\_\w+\_\w+")`

Comment: `re.match` takes a string as an argument. *It* (not the Python parser) parses it as a regular expression.

Comment: @rhavelka I tried doing that but then received this TypeError: match() missing 1 required positional argument: 'string'

Comment: @chepner so would I need to use re.search instead?

Comment: @AlphaQueUp looking at the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) you need a pattern and a string. so you would need something like `re.match(""H149xcV\_\w+\_\w+\_\w+", myFile)`

Comment: @AlphaQueUp No, you need to pass a *string* to the function. Python itself has no regular expression syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comments following your question, the parameter to match should be a string.  The one thing I'll add is that python3 has a r"" string delimiter for regular expressions.  Your code becomes this:

```
from Bio import SeqIO
import sys
import re 


    fasta_file = (sys.argv[1])
    for myfile in SeqIO.parse(fasta_file, "fasta"):
      if len(myfile) > 250:
       gene_id = myfile.id
       list = re.match(r"H149xcV_\w+_\w+_\w+", gene_id)
       print (">"+list.group(0))
```

The underscore _ is not a special regular expression character (as I recall) so it doesn't need to be escaped.

The `match()` function takes a regex and the string you are searching (so I added gene_id).  Lastly, you want to output `group(0)`.  group(0) means the whole match.  group(1) is from the first capturing paren (of which you have none) so stick with group(0).

Comment: Hi @Mark , how would I change the regex so that it only provides me with `>H149xcV_Fge342_r3_h2` and not`>H149xcV_Fge342_r3_h2_d1`. I would not like the very end part that consists of `d1`. So basically, how can I format it so it it only provides this `>H149xcV_Fge342_r3_h2`

Comment: The \w in the regex means "any word character".  This essentially means letters and numbers (although I'm sure I'm technically incorrect).  \w+ means 1 or more letters or numbers.  The underscore _ in the regex tells the parser to look for an underscore (literal match).  So, if you want the regex to not include '_d1' , omit the last 4 characters from your string.  Specifically, use r"H149xcV_\w+_\w+" instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`infoseq`](http://www.sacs.ucsf.edu/Documentation/emboss/infoseq.html) utility from the `EMBOSS` package and pipe the output (a table with sequence ids and lengths) through a one-liner in a scripting language of your choice. Here, I am using Perl for simplicity:

```
cat input.fasta | \
    infoseq -auto -only -name -length stdin | \
    perl -lane 'my ($name, $length) = @F; if ( !$seen{$name}++ && $length > 250 ) { print ">$name"; }' > output.fasta
```

Install `EMBOSS`, for example, using `conda`:

```
conda create --name emboss emboss
```

Comment: Hi @TimurShtatland unfortunately I am not allowed to use any additional utilities.